# How to SELECT only rows written to disk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Running `SQL Server 2012`. I'm wondering if it is possible to `SELECT` rows from a table, excluding rows that have not yet been committed - within the *current* transaction. I tried the `READPAST` hint, but it does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO A (Value) VALUES (1)
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO A (Value) VALUES(2)
SELECT * FROM A WITH (READPAST) -- Does not work!
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The above code will output two rows. I want it to only output the first row. Can this be achieved? (I know I can run the `SELECT` before the `INSERT` but unfortunately that is not possible in my application.)

Comment: I believe the `INSERT` is considered `committed` inside the current transaction. That's the problem.

Comment: No, shouldn't be at all unless the `commit` is getting executed.

Comment: @Rahul Isolation levels are about interaction with *other* transactions; within the current transaction, you see the state according to changes made so far, otherwise multiple statements in one transaction would be pretty useless.

Comment: @IMSoP, yep that's correct. my interpretation to the question was wrong.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Could you not just exclude the inserted row in the select where value <> 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of a way of making SQL Server treat writes in the own transaction as foreign. Therefore, you must read from a different transaction. **This is quite easy if you can make the application do it.**

If you *need* T-SQL code to do it, then you might consider using a **loopback linked server**. This sounds like a horrible hack, though, and I'm not even sure loopback linked servers are supported.

And I'd like to clean up a small misconception: Whether rows are committed or not has no direct relation to whether the pages they are stored on have been written to disk yet.

Answer (score 1):

Backup the table in a temp one before the insert with

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM a
```

then use the temp backup instead of the regular table with you code (the part in the transaction) it'll be

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM a 
INSERT INTO A (Value) VALUES(2)
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```